# Dynamics Advanced Find on 2 entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, advanced-search

I want to do an advanced find on a field on the Contact form and also a field from an extension entity but want to do an OR rather than an AND but it doesn't seem to let me. I want to make a marketing list picking both of these fields.

Comment: It might not be possible in Advanced Find. This article might help: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de488189-a44f-4a33-be55-cb9d6c0f1659/fetchxml-conditions-on-linked-entities?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply Aron

Answer (score 0):

You could try a calculated field on your extension entity that references the field from the Contact. I assume your extension entity has a lookup to Contact. So create a new calculated field on the extension entity of the same type as the field on Contact that you need. The calculation will be "contact.fieldname" where "contact" is the name of the lookup relationship and "fieldname" is the field on the contact that you need.

Now the calculated field on the extension entity will contain the same data from the field on the Contact and you can use Advanced Find to "OR" these two fields together since they are on the same entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with an **aliased** condition

This is done by:

1. Giving your Link Entity an `alias` value
2. Create an `or` filter
3. In your condition, specify the `entityname` which is a reference to the Link Entity's `alias`

For example, this query will retrieve Contact's First and Last Names and the Account's Name where either the Contact or the Account is active (as an inner join)

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="contact" >
    <attribute name="firstname" />
    <attribute name="lastname" />
    <filter type="or" >
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition entityname="ParentAccount" attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentcustomerid" alias="ParentAccount" >
      <attribute name="name" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

So in this example-query you can see:

1. `Account` is the Link Entity and I've given it the "ParentAccount" `alias`
2. The filter is applied to the `Contact` entity and the Link Entity has no criteria
3. The condition for the Account Status specifies the "ParentAccount" `entityname`

Comment: Thanks you for you reply.